Should operating system related tags be all synonyms?
We have [ios], [osx], [windows] and [windows7], most of them have not been used at all. Should there be a tag [os] created and have all those other tags be synonyms for it? If someone discusses some issue with a specific system, they usually refer to it in the title or the body anyway.

I would argue that each major platform deserves its own tag - i.e. merge windows7 into windows but leave osx distinct. ios should probably remain distinct along with android
